# Django Migration, cant find `User` field

Tags: python, django, migration

```
class Tld(models.Model): #TODO...resolve `User` table issue for FKtoClient
    #other fields
    FKtoClient = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

When I try to run:
`python ../manage.py makemigrations Myapp`

it says :

```
Myapp.Tld.FKtoClient: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
Myapp.Tld.FKtoClient: (fields.E307) The field Myapp.Tld.FKtoClient was declared with a lazy reference to 'Myapp.user', but app 'Myapp' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

How can I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: you didn't import `User` from `django.contrib.auth.models`

Comment: So `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` ?

Comment: This is included on line 1 of my file.

Comment: remove quotes, Django will treat it as string, means this model is inside the current app, which is not

Comment: Thanks @Lemayzeur

Comment: Or, reference the app as part of the string: `'auth.User'`, then you don't need to import it.